# Missing Content Type: "Enterprise Wiki Page" missing in "Page Layout Content Types"

Tags: 2013, administration

We have a 2 webapplications.

One can create Enterprise wiki sites, the other can't.

The ULS says missing contentType with ID `0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39004C1F8B46085B4D22B1CDC3DE08CFFB9C`

I have narrowed that content type down to "Enterprise Wiki Page".

- On webapplication 1 that contenttype exists.
- On Webapplication 2, that contenttype is missing.

Both site collections on both webapplications have Publishing enabled.

So what could be wrong?  Why would we be missing the "Enterprise Wiki Page" layout?

This doesn't allow us to create wiki sites.